# Problem solving i have a task for sorting with this small example but i cant get the idea anyhelp?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, angular, react-native

I have an array that comes from the backend sorted with this format below like this example :

```
const Data = [
    {id: 1, name: "jack"},
    {id: 1, name: "george"},
    {id: 1, name: "morries"},
    {id: 2, name: "abdo"},
    {id: 2, name: "ezz"},
    {id: 3, name: "mostafa"},
    {id: 4, name: "hamo"},
];
```

I want a new array of unique ids with the all the associated names like so:

```
const newData = [
    {id:1, names:["jack","george","morries"]},
    {id:2, names:["abdo","ezz"]},
    {id:3, names:["mostafa"]},
    {id:4, names:["hamo"]}
]
```

Here is what I came up:

```
for (var i = 0; i <= Data.length; i++) {
if (newData.length > 0) {
    for (var j = 0; j <= newData.length; j++) {
        if (newData[j].id === Data[i].id) {
            null
        }
        else newData.push(Data[i])
    }
}
else newData.push(Data[i])
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can reduce the array by finding the index.

```js
const Data = [ { id: 1, name: "jack" }, { id: 1, name: "george" }, { id: 1, name: "morries" }, { id: 2, name: "abdo" }, { id: 2, name: "ezz" }, { id: 3, name: "mostafa" }, { id: 4, name: "hamo" }, ];

const results = Data.reduce((previous,{id,name})=>{ 
       let index = previous.findIndex(item=>item.id === id);
       if(index > -1){
           previous[index].names.push(name);
       }else{
           previous.push({id:id,names:[name]});
       }
       return previous;
  },[]);
  console.log(results);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can refer

```
let map = new Map<number,string[]>();
this.Data.forEach(item => {
  if(map.has(item.id)){
    map.get(item.id).push(item.name);
  }else{
    map.set(item.id, [item.name]);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

https://jsfiddle.net/Jairusmartin/wd4scpr1/5/

```
const Data = [
    {id: 1, name: "jack"},
    {id: 1, name: "george"},
    {id: 1, name: "morries"},
    {id: 2, name: "abdo"},
    {id: 2, name: "ezz"},
    {id: 3, name: "mostafa"},
    {id: 4, name: "hamo"},
];
var new_array = [];

for (var i = 0; i < Data.length; i++) {
    var data_id = Data[i].id;
    var data_name = Data[i].name;

    // Make Unique array of ID, return index of that ID
    var ref_index = add(new_array, data_id);

    //Push name to index of that array
    new_array[ref_index].names.push(data_name);
  
}

console.log(new_array);

// Ensure unique array of ID
function add(data_array, id_value) {
  var index = data_array.findIndex(x => x.id === id_value);
  console.log(index);
  // if not found
  if (index === -1) {
    // add ID to new array
    data_array.push({ id: id_value, names: []});
    index = data_array.findIndex(x => x.id === id_value);
  } 
  
  // return id
  return index;
}
```